# JavaFX and Scene Builder ImageView

Tags: image, java-8, imageview, javafx-8, scenebuilder

When I add ImageView to the Scene Builder and set the image path, the image loads correctly in Scene Builder but the path looks like this: `"..\..\..\..\..\resources\background.jpg"`. In the `build.xml` file I added a line which copies resources folder from the project root to dist folder after the build and it works fine, but the Image won't load when I start application, because the paths are different. How can I solve this without using static/absolute paths?

Comment: Put the images in a resource folder that's is a part of the project structure.

Comment: @Sedrick Problem is that I have over 1 GB of images which will be used by the app.